# iPhone volume - ringer vs. volume?

Tags: iphone, audio

When I'm adjusting the volume on my iPhone, I've noticed that sometimes it says "ringer" as I adjust it, and sometimes it says "volume"; also, sometimes it says "volume (headphones)".  What determines when the volume buttons are adjusting the volume vs. the ringer, and what is the *difference* between the two actions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your ringer volume adjusts the volume of the sound coming out of the phone when it's ringing. If the phone is not playing media (i.e. no sound is coming out of it) then the volume buttons on the side adjust the ringer volume.

If you are playing media (music, video, etc) out the internal speakers, then the buttons on the side adjust the volume of that media coming out those speakers.

Finally, when you have headphones plugged in, the iPhone knows this and has a separate volume for headphones. Using the volume buttons will adjust the headphones volume when headphones are plugged in.

The reason why these are separate is because sometimes you want to mute your ringer, but still want to listen to media (or vice versa), and because the headphone and internal speaker volumes are different and need to be adjusted separately.

Comment: Also, most games use the non-ringer volume control, but some do use the ringer volume for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to adjust the volume, but are only getting the option to adjust the ringer, push the home button while you are adjusting the volume buttons and it will switch to volume...

Comment: That's because you're then adjusting the volume to Siri, which doesn't change the system volume either?