# How many kinds of volume are there on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sound-volume

And how can I change them?

I believe the following all have independent volume levels, although there could be some overlap:

- Ringer and Alerts (as defined in settings)
- Alarm clock
- Phone calls (separate for earpiece and speaker?)
- Media (and apps in general?)
- Siri
- External devices (e.g. earbuds or bluetooth)

Is there somewhere I can set them all, or is there at least a definitive list?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iPhone volume - ringer vs. volume?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/iphone-volume-ringer-vs-volume)